# Promises returns null

Tags: javascript

I'm getting some cars from another system.
getCar returns a promise. All works well but when I send multiple ids and one of them doesn't exist, I get a null entry in the array `cars`

[carObject, ..., ***null***]

```
    const carPromises = cars.map(car=> getCar(car.id));
    const cars = await Promise.all(carPromises );
    console.log(`Car Data -> ${JSON.stringify(cars)}`);
```

```
export const getCar = async (carId: number) => {
try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${baseUrl}/car/${carId});
    const car = response.data;
    return car;
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

If there any way to just remove the null entries from the array or just ignore them somehow?

Comment: This just wraps what `getCar()` returns, which for all we know could be `null`.

Comment: It returns a promise or null if catch is thrown

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Would this be helpful? https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-remove-null-values-from-array